# Basic jQuery with JSON Parsing

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am trying to parse some very basic JSON, but I don't know where I'm going wrong when trying to display it to the screen.

Am I not GRABBING the data correctly, such as, "data.re1Code"?
I hope someone can shed some light onto my basic question sorry.

JSON Data

```
[
    {
        "rep1FullName": "Justin Giesbrecht",
        "rep1Code": "dc",
    }
]
```

Javascript

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "testJSONData.php",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {

  $("#output").append(data.rep1FullName);

},
  error: function () { alert("Error"); }
}); // End of generated json
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The brackets [] make data a JSON array with your object as the 0th element so to get "Justin Giesbrecht" use the code: `$("#output").append(data[0].rep1FullName);` or remove the brackets and make the JSON:

```
{
        "rep1FullName": "Justin Giesbrecht",
        "rep1Code": "dc",
    }
```

Comment: Well the reason i'm getting the data that way, is how PHP uses json_encode(). Never thought about that issue. Thank you that worked great!

Answer (score 1):

Your data is an array.

So you'd want

```
$("#output").append(data[0].rep1FullName);
```

Comment: Well the reason i'm getting the data that way, is how PHP uses json_encode(). Never thought about that issue. Thank you that worked great!

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a jSon array so you would need to access it via `data[0].rep1FullName` or return the jSon as below and then use `data.rep1FullName`

```
{
    "rep1FullName":"Justin Giesbrecht",
    "rep1Code":"dc"
}
```

Comment: Well the reason i'm getting the data that way, is how PHP uses json_encode(). Never thought about that issue. Thank you that worked great!

Answer (score 1):

Also, remove the last comma from the object notation.

```
[
    {
        "rep1FullName": "Justin Giesbrecht",
        "rep1Code": "dc" // <-- No comma, breaks in IE if you have a comma.
    }
]
```

Some of the other posters did this, but didn't mention it.